# convert byte to string in rails

Tags: ruby, encoding, base64, byte

how to convert byte data to a string so I perform base64 decode on it and then zlib decompress it.

example: `data = b'eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ=='`

```
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(Base64.decode64(bin_to_hex(data)))

def bin_to_hex(s)
s.unpack('C*').first
end
```

I'm getting `"\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` also getting `undefined method`unpack'`

Comment: I removed [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag because this question has nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: `b'eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ=='` looks like a [Python byte literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Where does this data come from?

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating things. I have no idea what the leading `b` in data literal is supposed to mean, but this would work:

```
require 'base64'
Zlib::Inflate.inflate Base64.decode64('eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ==')
#⇒ "hello"
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is that the data is stored in the database with leading b => `b'eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ=='` so i guess i will just remove the b when I read the data.

Comment: Excuse me? `b'eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ=='` is not a valid Ruby. Is it `"b'eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ=='"`? If yes, remove `b` _and_ inner quotes.

Comment: make sense, thanks @Aleksei Matiushkin. one quick question, I'm trying append the data into an existing key, `object.websites.map do |v|  v.attributes.merge(decompressed_data) end` however, im getting the following error `no implicit conversion of Array into Hash`

Comment: Are you kidding? I have no idea what all these variables contain and where the error is raised from. Post another question.

Comment: Oh sorry about that man, I guess the question, if you have a datatype as array, how can you append it to a Hash. I can also post a new question, thanks.

Comment: Ah, `attributes` is a hash and `decompressed_data` is an array? Just add it to the hash under some key, like `v.attributes['decompressed_data'] = decompressed_data` or like.

Comment: yep that works, thanks a lot @Aleksei Matiushkin, appreciate your help!